# In excel how can I return the number of unique values in one column based on criteria in another column

Tags: excel

I have a set of data that includes `Sku` Value in Column A and Locations in Column C, but locations are duplicated in the data. I'm trying to create a formula that will let me enter a `Sku` into cell `H2` and returns the number of unique locations in column C that have a value in column A matching `H2`.

`Sku` values are alphanumeric and also contain a / (i.e. `ABCD123/A`) and Locations are alphanumeric (i.e. `123012A01`)

The number of rows of data will also potentially change so I'm trying to get it to work for any number of rows. I do not have access to the UNIQUE function in my version of excel.

Example of what finished sheet would look like

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO! Did you try with `COUNTIF` function?

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the new excel formulas `FILTER` & `UNIQUE` then:

```
=COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER(B2:B7,A2:A7=D2)))
```

---

If you don't have access to those formulas then you can use an array formula which must be confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

```
=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF(A2:A7=D3,MATCH(B2:B7,B2:B7,0)),ROW(B2:B7)-ROW(B2)+1)>0))
```

---

Image to relate equations to relevant ranges

[image]

Comment: I know you don't, but posting for others that do and find your question

Comment: Would be great if I did, but unfortunately I'm on a version of excel that doesn't have that, and I've been unable to get other methods to work so far.

Comment: @Greg updated with array formula that works. Did the easy one first, harder one second :P

Comment: It was a dumb error on my part, I set the range too low because I keyed the wrong cell range. Is there a way to make it look at the whole column regardless of how many rows are in the data set? If not I'll just set it to some absurdly high number and hope my data never surpasses that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this non array formula for non `O365` excel versions.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A11=H2)/COUNTIF(C2:C11,C2:C11&""))
```

[image]